# Get value cell from loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop a column and delete al rows where the word in the columns has "Vul" as the first 3 characters.

I have created this:

```
Sub DeleteRow()

Dim i As Long
Dim myValue As String
Dim myCel As String

With Sheets("template (2)")
    For i = 100000 To 1 Step -1
        myValue = Left(.Cells(i, "A"), 3)

        If myValue = "Vul " Then
            .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

But this line:  `myValue = Left(.Cells(i, "A"), 3)`    is wrong. What can i do to make it work?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: An object defined error. (hope it is well translated, the error is in Dutch)

Comment: Is there a worksheet with the exact name `template (2)`? Also, you may want to make it `WorkSheets("template (2)")` instead.

Comment: No, there is just one sheet with that name. The error number is 1004.

I changed it to WorkSheets now, but still the same error.

Comment: Do you have 100,000 rows? Maybe you should try finding the last row first, and start there.

Comment: As Mentioned, the sheet name may not be exact. 1009 is usually a subscript out of range.--You are using Left() and 3 characters, but asking if it is equal to 4 characters.....sheets() and worksheets() does not make a difference here.,,,,should also be`.Cells(i, "A").value`

Comment: The problem was i had no 100000 rows, so i changed it and now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work this way:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim MyValue As String
Set rng = Range("A1:A400")

For Each cell In rng

        MyValue = Left(cell.Value, 3)


        If MyValue = "Vul" Then


            cell.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: This way will run into problems, as you need to loop backwards when deleting rows.

Comment: @braX- yep, will miss multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
For i = LastRow To FirstRow+1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Left(Sheet.Cells(i, "A"), 3), "Val", 0)) Then
            Sheet.Rows(i).Delete
   End If
Next i
```